# BLE 5.1 direction finding algorithm implementation in python

Tags: python, algorithm, bluetooth-lowenergy, calculation, indoor-positioning-system

I need to implement BLE AoA Direction finding using PDDA (propagation direct data aquisition) algorithm in python as explained in the paper below. I am using a 12 antenna array as mentioned in this paper.

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9676583

I managed to solve till step (8), but could not implement step (9) onwards.
any pointers to the PDDA python implementation for BLE AoA or if it is too easy for someone to just write the code, I would really appreciate.
TIA.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The paper is not fully accessible to me, please add the relevant information to your question with an [edit]. Also, StackOverflow is not a free coding service, please tell us what exactly it is you need help with and why step 9 could not be implemented.